# Multivariate time series forecasting with LSTMs in Keras (on future data)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, prediction

So I have been using Keras to predict a multivariate time series. The dataset is a pollution dataset. The first column is what I want to predict and the remaining 7 are features. Dataset can be found here:
https://github.com/sagarmk/Forecasting-on-Air-pollution-with-RNN-LSTM/blob/master/pollution.csv

So what I want to do is to perform the following code on a test set without the "pollution" column. Let's say that there is new data for the features but not the pollution. So

1. How do I train the model without test data? (model.fit())
2. How do I predict new pollution data without future data on pollution? (model.predict())

To make it simple the dataset could be initially split into a training and testing dataset in the beginning, where the "pollution" column is removed from he testing dataset?

See below a simple code.
Here I simply import and process the dataset.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
import seaborn as sns
import plotly.express as px

# Import data
dataset = pd.read_csv("pollution.csv")
dataset = dataset.drop(['date'], axis = 1)
label, layer = pd.factorize(dataset['wnd_dir'])
dataset['wnd_dir'] = pd.DataFrame(label)
dataset=dataset.fillna(dataset.mean())
dataset.head()
```

After that I normalize the dataset.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

values = dataset.values
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaled = scaler.fit_transform(values)
scaled[0]
```

Then convert the normalized data into supervised form.

```
def to_supervised(dataset,dropNa = True,lag = 1):
    df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
    column = []
    column.append(df)
    for i in range(1,lag+1):
        column.append(df.shift(-i))
    df = pd.concat(column,axis=1)
    df.dropna(inplace = True)
    features = dataset.shape[1]
    df = df.values
    supervised_data = df[:,:features*lag]
    supervised_data = np.column_stack( [supervised_data, df[:,features*lag]])
    return supervised_data

timeSteps = 2

supervised = to_supervised(scaled,lag=timeSteps)
pd.DataFrame(supervised).head()
```

Now the dataset is split and transformed so that the LSTM network can handle it.

```
features = dataset.shape[1]
train_hours = round(dataset.shape[0]*0.7)
X = supervised[:,:features*timeSteps]
y = supervised[:,features*timeSteps]

x_train = X[:train_hours,:]
x_test = X[train_hours:,:]
y_train = y[:train_hours]
y_test = y[train_hours:]

print(x_train.shape,x_test.shape,y_train.shape,y_test.shape)
#convert data to fit for lstm
#dimensions = (sample, timeSteps here it is 1, features )

x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], timeSteps, features)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], timeSteps, features)

print(x_train.shape,x_test.shape)
```

Here the model is trained

```
#define the model
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense,LSTM

model = Sequential()
model.add( LSTM( 50, input_shape = ( timeSteps,x_train.shape[2]) ) )
model.add( Dense(1) )

model.compile( loss = "mae", optimizer = "adam")

history =  model.fit( x_train,y_train, validation_data = (x_test,y_test), epochs = 50 , batch_size = 72, verbose = 0, shuffle = False)
plt.pyplot.plot(history.history['loss'], label='train')
plt.pyplot.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='test')
plt.pyplot.legend()
#plt.pyplot.yticks([])
#plt.pyplot.xticks([])
plt.pyplot.title("loss during training")
plt.pyplot.show()
```

Lastly I plot the training data along with the test data.

```
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0],x_test.shape[2]*x_test.shape[1])

inv_new = np.concatenate( (y_pred, x_test[:,-7:] ) , axis =1)
inv_new = scaler.inverse_transform(inv_new)
final_pred = inv_new[:,0]

plt.pyplot.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.pyplot.plot(dataset['pollution'])
plt.pyplot.plot([None for i in dataset['pollution']] + [x for x in final_pred])
plt.pyplot.show()
```

Comment: Please, provide minimal code with a dummy sample.

Answer (score 0):

Predicting results with your neural network should be as simple as the below line of code. Passing new data that is in the same format as training data.

```
prediction = model.predict(features)
```

Do you have any code that you can provide? What issue are you running into?

Comment: But training data has to include the column of what we are trying to predict? While the future dataset only has features, i.e. one less column and therefore not the same format. I edited the post and added code to make the problem clearer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I.e. when the "test" dataset only consists of 8 feature columns and no column for the price?

It looks like you are asking a feature engeering question. You real dataset have nan value in different column which make predict failed , right ?

In this case , you can take commom solution:

fill nan value by the median/mean of correspoding column in trainset.

For example, you can fill future price by the median/mean of recently 14 days(aggregation length) prices of each product.

### UPDATE

When making future prediction, there may be a lot of features only have history(without plan) .
In traditional machine learning , if you want to predict a target depend on all feature, you need predict those future of features first .

But by LSTM , you can make prediction all in one , check [time_series#multi-output_models](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#multi-output_models)

Comment: No not at all, and that is not a good idea from a machine learning perspective? Since we want to predict the future data (price is changed to pollution after edit) it shouldn't matter what the data is. 0, mean or 100000. Please correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: @Lamar  Mean/median  history is just a common guess for future.  Unless you have the price plan , otherwise you have to drop the column or fill it with some value .  The more  solid future infomation the more precise prediction .